# How to change mail config quarkus at runtime

Tags: quarkus

I 'm using mailer in quarkus to send mail (https://quarkus.io/guides/mailer). By default, MailConfig has been configured in the application.properties file. So how can i configure MailConfig from database and can change MailConfig at runtime

Answer (score 0):

Any property under `quarkus.mailer` is a **runtime** property, which means you can change in any of the [supported](https://quarkus.io/guides/config-reference#configuration-sources) ways.

Comment: I have an email configuration management page that allows admin to change host mail, username/password. This information will be saved to the database and will be applied immediately to the MailClient when there are changes. I don't know any way to change MailClient at runtime without having to restart the application

Comment: Quarkus does not support reloading of configuration after the application has restarted.

Comment: The link supported just talks about the various levels of configuration sources, not how to actually change any particular value at runtime, if it's even possible. Personally I'm also fairly confused, as they call it a runtime property but then offer no suggestion in the documentation on how to update that value on a live running system.

Maybe in the programatic API we can update a value, but it's not clear from the documentation that this is possible or not outside of the name "runtime" property.

Comment: If I'm understanding the question correctly, I believe the answer to this is answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72110212/is-there-a-way-to-override-application-properties-programmatically